# Rails - How to retry in pessimistic locking?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pessimistic-locking

Rails Guide and lots of other tutorials show me how to rescue `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError` exception and do retry in optimistic locking. And I just curious can I do the same thing in pessimistic locking scenario.

Any reply is appreciate! :D

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "do the same thing in pessimistic locking scenario?" By definition, Rails won't throw that exception if you're using pessimistic locking.

Comment: thanks, i see that it is hardly to catch that error ```Mysql2::Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded``` and do retry as i expect, because that error is actually raised by mysql database rather than active record.

Comment: I think I see what you were asking now. It sounds like you've figured out what you have to do. Let me know if you have further questions about this.